# How to center vertical inside header?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a responsive header. I got two columns and want the `button` in the right column to be vertical centered.

I know I can center items using `top: 50%; margin-top: -xy px`, and my `button` although got a fixed `height: 40px.`

To use this method I wrapped my `button` inside a `div {position: relative}`. This does not work, as the `div` does not stretch its own height.

How can I solve this with css? First I thought about [Flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/), but it has quite some [lack of browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/x2ky9zk7/5/)</kbd>

Comment: Try tables https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/134/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code - remove floats, (use `display: inline-block` instead), remove the `.relative` div, etc.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/x2ky9zk7/7/)

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
header {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 0.2em;
}
header p {
  margin: 0;
}
header button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
}
.column-left {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.column-right {
  width: 29%;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
/* responsive */
@media (min-width: 200px) {
  header {
    padding: 1em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  header {
    padding: 1.5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  header {
    padding: 2em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  header {
    padding: 2.5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  header {
    padding: 3em;
  }
}
/* helpers */
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this div with `position: relative` and add `position: relative` to your `header` tag. You can even delete your `column-right` div.

Another solution:

```
header button {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); // instead of negative margin-top (it is useful when your button has dynamic height, supports IE9+ with -ms- prefix)
}
```

## **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x2ky9zk7/6/)**

Comment: simple and effective. Thanks for the hint!